# Is it possible to rename default directories in the users home folder?

Tags: macos, catalina

Can default folders such as Documents, Downloads, Music, etc be renamed to something else? Like how on a Linux system you could edit *user-dirs.dirs*?

The capitalisation of these direction bugs me as it interferes with my naming convention of everything being lowercase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you can't. If you mainly work with Terminal you can just set symlinks to make the folders also reachable via the names you are used to (`ln -s ~/Documents ~/doc` etc). This also works for Finder of course, your home directory may just look a bit cluttered then.

Comment: That's what I suspected. I see it used to be possible according to this https://www.macworld.com/article/1046866/renamesystemfolders.html I guess I will just create another 'user directory' inside my current user directory and symlink stuff.

Comment: @kevjohnston You'll find similar information on this site, but with more recent versions of macOS it got more and more difficult to rename these folders.